# How to save a trained NLTK POS-tagger

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I was wondering how to save a trained NLTK (Unigram)Tagger. I train a `Portuguese UnigramTagger` with the following code, depending on the corpus it may take a while for it to run, so I'd like to avoid rerunning it.

```
import nltk
from nltk import mac_morpho

def get_unigram_tagger():
  p_train = 0.9
  tagged_sents = mac_morpho.tagged_sents()
  size = int(len(tagged_sents)*0.9)
  train_sents = tagged_sents[:size]
  test_sents = tagged_sents[size:]
  uni_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(train_sents)
  print "Test accuracy =", uni_tagger.evaluate(test_sents)
  return uni_tagger
```

So I get `uni_tagger` from this function and I have to recompute it if I'm running the program again. Maybe I can save `uni_tagger` somehow so that next time I just need to read it (weights and such) from a file.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/alvations/spaghetti-tagger/blob/master/spaghetti.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like pickle to persist your model to disk.

```
import nltk
import pickle
from nltk import mac_morpho
def get_unigram_tagger():
  p_train = 0.9
  tagged_sents = mac_morpho.tagged_sents()
  size = int(len(tagged_sents)*0.9)
  train_sents = tagged_sents[:size]
  test_sents = tagged_sents[size:]
  uni_tagger = nltk.UnigramTagger(train_sents)
  print "Test accuracy =", uni_tagger.evaluate(test_sents)
  return uni_tagge
tagger = unigram_tagger()
s = pickle.dumps(tagger)
model2 = pickle.loads(s)
```

You can also used sklearn's replacement of pickle `(joblib.dump` & `joblib.load)`

```
from sklearn.externals import joblib
joblib.dump(tagger, 'filename.pkl') 
tagger3 = joblib.load('filename.pkl')
```

Sklearn claims that joblib is more efficient than pickle for larger numpy like model arrays.

You can read more here

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html